# How to disable clean or remove notification on android studio

Tags: android-studio, push-notification

I am working with firebase push notifications. So in my project , If I click on a notification , it should  open an interface call "UserDetailsActivity" . But i want disable delete  or clean notification before open "UserDetailsActivity" .

this is my code :

```
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d("msg", "onMessageReceived: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("message")+"hey "+remoteMessage.getSentTime());



   if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {



            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            if(remoteMessage.getData().get("title").equals("Pagamento")){
                HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                map.put("title",remoteMessage.getData().get("title"));
                map.put("Parametro1",remoteMessage.getData().get("Parametro1"));

                String Parametro1 = map.get("Parametro1");
                String[] seperater =Parametro1.split(":");
                String orderId =seperater[1];
                map.remove("Parametro1");
                map.put("orderId",orderId);

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, UserDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("pushNotification",map);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
                String channelId = "Default";
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_push_notificatioin)
                        .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                        .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()).setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent);;
                NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Default channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                    manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                }
                manager.notify((int) remoteMessage.getSentTime(), builder.build());
               stopForeground(true);
                startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserDetailsActivity.class));
                Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload:1 " );
            }

        }

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserDetailsActivity.class));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use unable to delete notification i have to add new line one notificationCompat.Bilder and it is:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId) 
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_push_notificatioin)
                                    .setOngoing(true)
```

**If set "setOngoing" notification is true then user can not delete it